# Unhashing a password or holding unhashed password C#

Tags: c#, hash, cryptography

BACKGROUND

I am making a personal password vault. I will be the only one that uses it and maintains it. I am doing it to practice cryptography as a personal project.

WHAT WORKS

I have a login page which is linked to a "Users" table in the database that stores my username and a password that has been salted and hashed. I have the method that will check what I type in the password field against the hashed/salted password within the database and that all works fine so I can log in successfully.

WHAT I REQUIRE HELP WITH IF POSSIBLE

I wanted my app to log me in and I have a list of all places I type in a password eg. other apps, websites etc. within a datagrid. I will click on the one I want, click a button and a messagebox will show up with an unhashed version of the password. From what I have read a hashed passsword is unhashable so didn't know what the best way to this would be, if at all possible, other than to store unhashed passwords (which defeats the object!).

Cheers

Comment: In addition to being too broad, you have a flawed understanding of encryption and hashing.  Hashing will not allow you to return the password.  That's why secure websites store a hash - they shouldn't be *able* to tell you your password.  If you need to store a password for retrieval, then you want to encrypt it.

Comment: hashed string cannot be unhashed

Comment: you don't 'unhash' it; you hash the entered password and see if it matches the hashed password that's stored!

Comment: Even more - you can't create hashed password at all because you don't know what hashing algorithm and additional data ("salt") used to construct the hash of password...

Comment: @DavidCrowell I am no master but I understand roughly how it works, hence, I stated I have a login form that requires a password which is then hashed and salted and checked against the already stored hash and salt of the password. I agree that the question may be too broad though as it is seeking to see if anyone has tried something like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A central principle of a hash is that it is *one way*, as you have read.  Since you want to be able to perform a two way conversion between your data and a secured version you need to use encryption, which is specifically designed to both encrypt and then later decrypt the data in question.

Comment: +1. I'd not say "whole point" in relation to this particular application of hashing... the one part is inability of random person to construct hash from string without knowing other details (like exact algorithm and extra data) thus making brute force enumeration of plain text passwords harder.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Sure, it's not the *only* important trait of a hash, it's one of a few.

Comment: @Servy this is what I was looking for! Thanks, what I was after was a two-way conversion.

Answer (score 3):

One way of doing this is to store plain text passwords and encrypt the file (or the blob) with a master password that you remember.

Any time you need access, you'd provide this master password and decrypt the file to access passwords.

Depending on your design, you can prompt for master password once (say app startup) or everytime.

And make sure you do not write or persist the plain text passwords anywhere **unencrypted**!

You can hold them in memory for the app's lifetime to make the UX easier so next time when the app starts up, you repeat the same process (i.e. ask for master password, un-encrypt, use and then quit).