# SHA1 Salted Hash

Tags: hash, salt

I'm working on Hashing and have just come across my first salted hash. I can't figure out how to separate or identify the salt from the hash. I have figured out how to get the encrypted message below, but just need this seperation.

I have been up for almost 24 hours working on it. Any help would be appreciated!

74c95cff4b3daa8a65ae413bfab10dc45d1a07b6

Comment: Are you trying to un-hash this? You can't [un-hash a hashed string, that's the point](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25571997/542251). It's one way encryption

Comment: Maybe explain what your trying to achive here in borad terms?

Comment: Normaly the salt is stored in another column. So if the user enters his password again you append the salt to his password and hash it. If the stored hash and the new generated hash are equal he entered the right password

Comment: I'm actually trying to figure out if there is a way to un-hash a password that was hashed with salt.

Comment: and I would use http://www.dcode.fr/sha1-hash to do so, but need to add both the hash and salt.

Comment: It's (virtually) impossible. It'd be pretty crappy encryption if everyone could just un-encrypt it at will

Comment: You could try and brute force it, for SHA-1 with a alpha numeric password of around 10 characters, that'd take around [16 years 280 days 11 hours 11 minutes 37 seconds and there are a mere 3760620109779060 password combinations](http://calc.opensecurityresearch.com/). I think that's unsalted though, so prob times that by a factor of 10...

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. The salt is added to the original string *before* it was hashed.

Its `sha1(str + salt)` not `sha1(str) + salt` so you cannot split it from the hash.

Comment: Ah, thanks! Do I have any options to try and get the password out of this? It's my little sisters Tumblr account. Anything at all, thanks!

Comment: How did you get this hash?